# getting selected value of IEnumerable<T> from Drop Down List

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, ienumerable

I have a dropdown list as below:

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = Students.GetStudents();
DropDownList1.DataBind();
-----------
```

I have a DataAccess Class as below:

```
public IEnumerable<StudentEntity> GetStudents()
{
List<StudentsEntity> studentsList = new List<StudentsEntity>();
studentsList = Service.GetList()  // some service getting a list of sutdents

return new BindingList<StudentEntity>(studentsList);
}
```

I have a DataObject Class as below:

```
public class StudentEntity : IComparable
{
  public string fullname { get {return firstName +", "+ lastName;}
  public string ID {get; set;}
  public string Height {get; set;}
  public string Firstname {get; set;}
  public string Lastname {get; set;}
  public int CompareTo(object obj)
  {
     StudentEntity entity = (StudentEntity) obj;
     return Lastname.CompareTo(entity.Lastname);
  }
}
```

At the UI level - the 'Students Fullname' is displayed in the dropdown list, so how can I get the 'ID' of the Selected Student from the DropDown List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the selected item from the DropDownList and cast it to an object of the type StudentEntity. Afterwards you can get the ID of that object. Pseudo code:

```
var selectedItem = myDropDown.SelectedItem as StudentEntity;
var ID = selectedItem.ID;
```

**Edit:**

'hvd' commented me correctly. Since this is in a webcontext, you'll have to achieve this a bit different. You can set the DataTextField and the DataValueField of the DropDownList. Bind the ID to the DataValueField and when you get the SelectedItem, get the Value-property and you have the ID.

```
var selectedItem = myDropDown.SelectedItem;
var ID = selectedItem.Value;
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading the documentation, and I can't check right now, but what I see is that [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem.aspx) isn't the data item, it's a `ListItem` object, which will not contain any `StudentEntity` properties.

Comment: You're right, didn't realise it was about web controls... Check edited answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler:

```
var id = ((StudentEntity)sender).Id;
```

Comment: What event handler? If it's an event of the dropdown list, the sender will be the dropdown list, not the `StudentEntity`.

Comment: Then it should be: var id = ((StudentEntity)((DropDownList)sender).SelectedItem).ID;